# $\mu\approx \nu$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|u_n\|_{L^2(X,\mu)}=0$ imply $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|u_n\|_{L^2(X,\nu)}=0$ ??

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a bounded metric space, $\mu$ be a positive finite measure on $(X,d)$. Assume that $\mathcal F$ is a linear subspace of $L^2(X,\mu)\bigcap L^2(X,\nu)$ containing an orthonormal basis $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of $L^2(X,\mu)$,  where $d\nu:=W\,d\mu$ with $1<W\in L^\alpha(X,\mu)$ for some $\alpha>1$. Can we prove that $\mathcal F$ is dense in $L^2(X,\nu)$? If it is wrong, then can you give an example? Thank you!

We observe that $\mathcal F$ is dense in $L^2(X,\mu)$, $\mu$ is equivalent to $\nu$ and $L^2(X,\nu)\subseteq L^2(X,\mu)$.

It is well-known that:
 Let $u_n, u\in L^2(X, \mu)$. Since $\mu(X)<\infty$, we have $\|u_n-u\|_{L^2(X,\mu)}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ if and only if $u_n$ converges to $u$ in $\mu$-measure, and $\{|u_n|^2\}$ is uniformly integrable with respect to $\mu$, i.e., for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
 $$
 \int_E|u_n|^2\,d\mu<\epsilon
 $$
for all $n\ge 1$ and any measurable subset $E\subseteq X$ such that $\mu(E)<\delta$.

Comment: Is $\mathcal F = F$?

Comment: Yes, it  was corrected in new version.